# Inconsistent AABB collision detection

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, javascript, aabb

I'm making an endless jumper as my first game and I'm running into some problems with the one-way collision detection.

Collisions are detected correctly most of the time but occasionally the player inexplicably falls through the platform.

I suspect that it is ghosting through the platforms but I can't see why and I'm too close to it to be able to identify the source of the problem.

My code:

This loop is located within the update method of the global platforms object. this._platforms refers to the array of Platform objects.

```
 for (i = 0, len = this._platforms.length; i < len; i++) {
            var p = this._platforms[i];

            p.proximity = Math.abs(p.x / 2 - player.x / 2) + Math.abs(p.y / 2 - player.y / 2);

            if (p.closest()) {
                if (p.collision()) {
                    player.onplatform = true;
                    player.y = p.y - player_s_right.height;
                } else {
                    player.onplatform = false;
                }
            }
 ... 
}
```

It loops through the platform objects, running a collision test only if the platform is the closest one to the player.

Here are the closest() and collision() checks respectively:

```
// Return whether current platform is the closest to the player
Platform.prototype.closest = function() {

    var minprox = Math.min.apply(Math, platforms._platforms.map(function (obj) {
        return obj.proximity;
    }));

    return this.proximity === minprox;
}

// Collision detection
Platform.prototype.collision = function() {

    var px = player.direction > 0 ? player.x + 15 : player.x,
        px2 = player.direction > 0 ? player.x + player_s_right.width : player.x + player_s_right.width - 15,
        py = player.y + player_s_left.height,
        py2 = player.y + player_s_right.height + player.yvelocity,

        platx2 = this.x + platform_s.width,
        platy2 = this.y + platform_s.height;

    if (((px > this.x && px < platx2) || (px2 > this.x && px2 < platx2)) && (py2 >= this.y && py2 <= platy2) && py <= this.y) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

If anyone can shed some light on this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you in a state where you could post a link to your game? Something like collision detection is difficult to debug with just a few code snippets as the current state of the game is required to find the problem. For example, if you are using [frame-base animation](http://blog.sklambert.com/using-time-based-animation-implement/), then you might be skipping frames past your intended platform. *Disclaimer: I wrote that article.*

Comment: If it helps [here](https://github.com/Shaffan/Ninjump) is a link to my Github repo. Great article by the way @Steven Lambert

Answer (score 0):

It seems your proximity algorithm only checks proximity of the top-left (?) corner of the platform. For example if we have scenario like:

```
       P
   AAAAAABBBBB
```

where we have player P and platforms A and B. Here closest() would return B as the closest platform and then B.collision() would return false.

Comment: At the moment platforms are never close enough to each other for this to be an issue, and so I was satisfied with a very basic proximity check. I will take note of this moving forward, though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your proximity calculation wasn't working correctly when two platforms were right next to one another. I'm not sure what type of proximity calculation you are trying to use, but I think using the [distance between two points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916953/get-distance-between-two-points-in-canvas) would give a more correct result. Changing the proximity to use that seems to make it work.

```
var px = player.direction > 0 ? player.x + 15 : player.x,
    pwidth = player_s_right.width - 15;
    a = (px + pwidth / 2) - (p.x + platform_s.width / 2);
    b = (player.y + player.sprite.height / 2) - (p.y + platform_s.height / 2)

p.proximity = Math.sqrt( a*a + b*b );
```